# How to get the number of processor groups in Java?

Tags: java, cpu

Considering an example like this:
[image: processor grounps]

Is there a way to get the number of:
- Groups
- NUMA nodes (or equivalent on Unix) per Group
- Sockets per NUMA node
- Cores per Socket
- LPs per Core
Using Java?

Answer (score 1):

You need a third-party library. You cannot get that info from the java runtime itself.

The only one I know is this one https://github.com/oshi/oshi, but I don't know if it has the such a detailed information. May be you can take a look at its documentaron.

Probably there are other third-party libraries. And for sure, you will need to use one.

Comment: That moment when you're implementing code in your library and search SO to find hints, and you find someone asked the same question and mentioned your library as an answer.  :)    OSHI (linked above) will soon have this capability. The Windows implementation is done and I'll be working on Linux and Unix next.